# Calculate loss (MSE) on neural network output with different measurement units

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am training a neural network with pytorch. The input/features is 6-dimensional and of the same unit of measurement. The outputs/labels is 7-dimensional with 2 different unit of measurements (in my case mm and deg). How can I compute a MSE loss on this output? The problem is that 1 deg doesn't correspond to 1 mm. So even if I normalize my data, the network cannot differentiate between the units and treats degrees like mms. I know that some people use empirical weight factors to scale the different labels to get better results. **Is there a better way?**

I know I could train simply two different networks with one output being in mm and the other in deg.

I am thankful for any informed advise!

Comment: As far as your network's output is the same with the shape of your true labels, calculating MSE loss shouldn't be a concern. Do you mean that your outputs are in the shape of `(7, 2)`, with last two being `mm` and `deg`? What is 7 there? Is it the batch_size or sequence length...?

Comment: The shape of the output is (7,1). It has nothing to do with the batch_size. I justed wanted to provide some details but there are not relevant.

Comment: Ok. To make it more clear, you may post the snippet (like your network) that you have tried. That will make things easier to trace and solve.